# How to pass a parameter to HEREDOC?

Tags: php, heredoc

I try to pass a variable to HEREDOC, when I call it from HTML:

```
<?php   
$slider = <<<SLIDER
    <li><img src="images/banner-1{$mobile}.jpg" /></li>
SLIDER;
?>
```

But it doesn't update when the HEREDOC is called:

```
<ul id="slider mobile">
<?php 
    $mobile = '-mobile';
    echo $slider; 
?>
</ul>
```

Can it be used as a function or something?

Comment: Variables in strings are evaluated/replaced when the string with variable is defined, not when you use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can more easily do what you're attempting to achieve if you instead make the HEREDOC return from a function that you can pass an argument to:

```
function slider_string( $mobile ) {
    return <<<SLIDER
        <li><img src="images/banner-1{$mobile}.jpg" /></li>
SLIDER;
}
```

Then later you can perform this mutation.

```
<ul id="slider mobile">
<?php echo slider_string( '-mobile' ); ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I am trying to do. Thought about it at the end. Thanks.

Comment: [I'd call that an "assist"...](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33505400/revisions) ^ ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii-. Good call! Damned leading spaces in HEREDOC's.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Hehe yeah. I thought that would've helped ;-) *Cheers*

Comment: @AbraCadaver hahaha! *woohoo!!!* ;-) thanks. well, maybe more like 0.25 ;-) Ohgodwhy did most of the work lol

Comment: The only problem is that if I use any other variables in the string, I have to pass them all one by one on each function call. But this is a minor inconvenience.